# What should I look for when I look for sewing machine needles?

Tags: sewing, sewing-machine

I am thinking of buying new needles for my Silvercrest SNM 33 B1 sewing machine, but I do not know whether sewing machine needle have a specific compatibility with specific a sewing machine manufacturers or have a universal one.

So I wonder what characteristics should I know when I look for replacement needles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Home sewing machines use the same style of needle. Any store that sells sewing supplies for home crafters (as opposed to manufacturers) should have that type of sewing machine needles, and only that type. If they have multiple brands of sewing machine needle, any brand should work, and the choice is merely one of brand preference. The part that fits into the machine is round with one flat side.

Needles are chosen based on what type of fabric you plant to sew, not based on the machine brand. If you plan to sew normal garment fabrics, get universal needles. You'll need specialized needles for certain types of fabric: stretchy knit fabrics, thick and tough fabrics like denim or upholstery fabric, leather, or for quilting. Here's a [basic "choose the right type of needle" guide](https://www.sewessential.co.uk/blog/how-to-choose-the-right-sewing-machine-needle/) for more details.

That said, it's a good idea to consult your machine's user manual to make sure your machine doesn't have unique requirements. If you don't have the user manual, you should make your next project finding a replacement copy. Most sewing machine manuals are available somewhere on the internet for download, although be sure your virus protection software is up to date before downloading anything. Or you may be able to find a physical copy for sale. Once you have a manual, treat it like an essential part of the machine, and always keep it with your sewing machine so it doesn't get lost.

[This site](https://en.sewingguide.de/product-overview/silvercrest-snm33b1) seems to be the official site for the Lidl Silvercrest brand sewing machine, and it has manuals you can download, as well as some maintenance and troubleshooting information you can view without downloading anything. Based on a few of the diagrams I could see, it does appear that this brand uses the normal home sewing machine needle.